# Paginate related data in hasMany relationship

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, pagination

I'm having some trouble trying to paginate related data in a hasMany relationship

I have two models - Collection and Item
Collection hasMany Item
Item belongsTo Collection

In the Collection view.ctp it shows the collection details for the ID being passed along with related data of the Items. It receives this data from a find "first" call.

```
$this->set('collection', $this->Collection->find('first', $options));
```

With the resulting array looking like:

```
array(
    'Collection' => array(
        'id' => '4fc923f5-0a58-453f-9507-0c0c86106d80',
        'name' => '<collection_name>'
    ),

    'Item' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '4fc92403-000c-4ed2-9dae-0c0c86106d80',
            'name' => 'Item1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '4fc9241b-35ec-4810-b511-0c0c86106d80',
            'name' => 'Item2'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '4fc96e5d-ad74-4c05-a9da-0c0c86106d80',
            'name' => 'Item3'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'id' => '4fc96e64-a110-4036-bea2-0c0c86106d80',
            'name' => 'Item4'
        )
    )
```

Now I can get the same results from this paginate call except there is the added 0 index

```
$this->set('items', $this->paginate('Collection', array('Collection.id'=>$id)));

array(
    (int) 0 => array(

        'Collection' => array(
            'id' => '4fc923f5-0a58-453f-9507-0c0c86106d80',
            'name' => '<collection_name>'
        ),

        'Item' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '4fc92403-000c-4ed2-9dae-0c0c86106d80',
                'name' => 'Item1'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '4fc9241b-35ec-4810-b511-0c0c86106d80',
                'name' => 'Item2'
            ),
            (int) 2 => array(
                'id' => '4fc96e5d-ad74-4c05-a9da-0c0c86106d80',
                'name' => 'Item3'
            ),
            (int) 3 => array(
                'id' => '4fc96e64-a110-4036-bea2-0c0c86106d80',
                'name' => 'Item4'
            )
      )
  )
);
```

I can perform an array_shift on the array returned but then the pagination doesn't work. I can try creating a custom paginate function for this but wanted to know if there's a simplier way to do this with the standard paginate I'm using since it has the data I want, just extra first array parent element [0].

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Well, paginate is *suposed* to do this? You're pagination the results, which will *normally* return a *list* of records. In your case, the 'list' contains only a single row (row 0). However, if your intent is to paginate records from the `Item` model, not the `Collection` model, you should modify your paginate and paginate the `Item` model. If you need some help with that, leave a comment or update your question using the [edit] link

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will update paginate from item. I was able to add 'findType'=> 'first' to the paginate in Collection and that gave me the same array as the find 'first' but paginate still not working there. I think I'm approaching this wrong trying to do with the collection model when, like you said, I should be doing from the item model. thanks again

Comment: That was my issue, but I also realized that my foreach in my view was messed up. Thanks again for the tip and spurring my head a bit more.

Comment: Glad I could help. Hope you will manage to ge what you want, otherwise post a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

// Don't pull in child data, we'll fetch that manually.
$this->Collection->contain(); // Assuming you have this behavior.

// Get the collection.
$collection = $this->Collection->find('first', $options);

// Conditions
$this->paginate['Item'] = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Item.collection_id' => $collection['Collection']['id'];
    )
);

// Get the items
$items = $this->paginate('Item');

// Return to original child model structure.
array_walk($items, function(&$v) { // Anonymous functions requires PHP 5.3
    $v = $v['Item'];
});

// Add it to the collection array.
$collection['Item'] = $items;

?>
```

That's the way I implement pagination on child models.  Give it a shot, might work for you too.

-A

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes this is what I did. was trying to post my own answer but stackover flow wasn't allowing me to.   $this->paginate = array(
      'Item' => array(
       'recursive' => 1,
       'limit' => 5,
       'conditions' => array('Item.collection_id' => $id),
       'order' => 'Item.name asc'
       )

Comment: the just called $this->set('items', $this->paginate('Item'));

Comment: Ah, I only added the array restructuring so I could set it all into one variable. :)

Comment: yeah, that is nice. didn't think of it but may come in handy in future.